# File comparison, one-to-many

Tags: windows-7, automation, diff, file-comparison

I need a program that allows comparing one text file to many others without having to open each one manually.

This is how it would work:
1) select the file which all others will be compare with
2) drag and drop the other files to start the comparison
3) the first pair with be displayed and as soon as that first comparison is dismissed the second would be displayed, and so on until every comparison is done

More details:
every file contains only text, there aren't any binary files
there are in different folders, some even in different drives
a clone/duplicate finder is not the solution, content of the files is what's important
I'm using windows 7

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `comp` and `fc` command line tools as a part of Windows 7. You could potentially script around them to achieve what you want.

Comment: Since the files are in several different folders and hard drives and i can't possibly move them to a single folder this solution is very impractical.

Comment: Also, i don't know scripting and i would prefer a visual solution using drag and drop to select the files.

Comment: Then you're fresh out of luck I suspect as what you want to do is quite specific.